# Using python Requests, how do i pull necessary info from page content that is in between <script> content I need <script>

Tags: python, request, python-requests

Hello guys thanks for stopping by to help. I'm having an issue pulling data from a response using python requests. Here is the url to the page that im attempting to pull from    `https://kith.com/collections/footwear/products/timberland-6-classic-premium-black`  search "inventory" to find the part i need

and heres a part of the page source that i need....specifically this(product: {"id":4033565511,"title":"Timberland 6\" Classic...................) enitre part. want to pull the product info and inventory.

```
<script>
     var selectCallback = function(variant, selector) {
     timber.productPage({
  money_format: "${{amount}}",
  variant: variant,
  selector: selector
});
};

jQuery(function($) {

  new Shopify.OptionSelectors('productSelect', {
    product: {"id":4033565511,"title":"Timberland 6\" Classic Premium - Black","handle":"timberland-6-classic-premium-black","description":"\u003cmeta charset=\"utf-8\"\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eClassic 6\" Construct silhouette\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eWaterproof\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eTriple-stitch construction\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eNubuck upper\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eLeather collar\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eGoodyear welt\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eAnti-Fatigue sole technology\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e&nbsp;\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cul\u003e\u003c\/ul\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eStyle: TB010073001\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eColor: Black&nbsp;\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eMaterial: Nubuck\u003c\/p\u003e","published_at":"2016-12-16T15:53:00-05:00","created_at":"2016-01-14T22:41:35-05:00","vendor":"TIMBERLAND","type":"Boot","tags":["10616","6\"","boot","boots","classic","footwear","mens","premium","tb010073001","timb6","timberland","Timberland 6\" Classic Premium - Black"],"price":19000,"price_min":19000,"price_max":19000,"available":true,"price_varies":false,"compare_at_price":0,"compare_at_price_min":0,"compare_at_price_max":0,"compare_at_price_varies":false,"variants":[{"id":13835416519,"title":"7.5","option1":"7.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"000906995042","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"Timberland 6\" Classic Premium - Black - 7.5","public_title":"7.5","options":["7.5"],"price":19000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":20,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":13835416583,"title":"8","option1":"8","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"000906995059","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"Timberland 6\" Classic Premium - Black - 8","public_title":"8","options":["8"],"price":19000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":33,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":13835416647,"title":"8.5","option1":"8.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"000906995066","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"Timberland 6\" Classic Premium - Black - 8.5","public_title":"8.5","options":["8.5"],"price":19000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":17,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":13835416071,"title":"10","option1":"10","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"000906995097","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"Timberland 6\" Classic Premium - Black - 10","public_title":"10","options":["10"],"price":19000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":14,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":13835416135,"title":"10.5","option1":"10.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"000906995103","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"Timberland 6\" Classic Premium - Black - 10.5","public_title":"10.5","options":["10.5"],"price":19000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":16,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":13835416199,"title":"11","option1":"11","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"000906995110","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"Timberland 6\" Classic Premium - Black - 11","public_title":"11","options":["11"],"price":19000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":29,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":13835416263,"title":"11.5","option1":"11.5","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"000906995127","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"Timberland 6\" Classic Premium - Black - 11.5","public_title":"11.5","options":["11.5"],"price":19000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":5,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":13835416327,"title":"12","option1":"12","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"000906995134","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"Timberland 6\" Classic Premium - Black - 12","public_title":"12","options":["12"],"price":19000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":11,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":13835416391,"title":"13","option1":"13","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"000906995141","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":true,"name":"Timberland 6\" Classic Premium - Black - 13","public_title":"13","options":["13"],"price":19000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":7,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null},{"id":13835416455,"title":"14","option1":"14","option2":null,"option3":null,"sku":"761020219604","requires_shipping":true,"taxable":true,"featured_image":null,"available":false,"name":"Timberland 6\" Classic Premium - Black - 14","public_title":"14","options":["14"],"price":19000,"weight":1361,"compare_at_price":0,"inventory_quantity":0,"inventory_management":"shopify","inventory_policy":"deny","barcode":null}],"images":["\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/DSC_3024.jpg?v=1481921739","\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/DSC_2984_98470a33-1b03-43e3-8daa-0051a76293cc.jpg?v=1481921739","\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/DSC_3010_79958e86-fc54-4d8f-97e8-9583d53b21e2.jpg?v=1481921739","\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/DSC_2997_06c9a64c-f701-4778-9f51-e49130f9e027.jpg?v=1481921739","\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/DSC_2988.jpg?v=1481921739"],"featured_image":"\/\/cdn.shopify.com\/s\/files\/1\/0094\/2252\/products\/DSC_3024.jpg?v=1481921739","options":["Size"],"content":"\u003cmeta charset=\"utf-8\"\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eClassic 6\" Construct silhouette\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eWaterproof\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eTriple-stitch construction\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eNubuck upper\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eLeather collar\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eGoodyear welt\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eAnti-Fatigue sole technology\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003e&nbsp;\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cul\u003e\u003c\/ul\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eStyle: TB010073001\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eColor: Black&nbsp;\u003c\/p\u003e\n\u003cp\u003eMaterial: Nubuck\u003c\/p\u003e"},
    onVariantSelected: selectCallback,
    enableHistoryState: true
  })
```

THANK YOU!!!

Comment: you can use `requests` module.
`import requests; rs = requests.get('https://kith.com/collections/footwear/products/timberland-6-classic-premium-black');` Then you have to parse entire unicode response `for ln in rs.text.splitlines(): if 'product: {"id"' in ln: LINE = ln` here `LINE` will contain the line in response which you might want. But you have to process it to use it actually as it will have lot of unicodes.

Comment: VERY HELPFUL AND WORKED PERFECT! THANK YOU SO MUCH